# Floyd-Warshall snippet keeps returning empty matrix in Javascript

Tags: javascript, adjacency-matrix, floyd-warshall

I've been trying to use the Floyd-Marshall algorithm to solve an excercise but it keeps returning a matrix only with zeros. Here's the code:

```
// Adjacency matrix

let am = [[0,0,0,1,1,1], 
          [0,0,1,0,1,0], 
          [0,1,0,1,0,1], 
          [1,0,1,0,0,0], 
          [1,1,0,0,0,0], 
          [1,0,1,0,0,0]]


// Floyd-Warshall algorithm

for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
        for (k = 0; k < n; k++) {

            if (am[i][j] > am[i][k] + am[k][j]) {
                am[i][j] = am[i][k] + am[k][j];
            }

        }
    }
}

return am;
```

It returns

```
 [[0,0,0,0,0,0], 
  [0,0,0,0,0,0], 
  [0,0,0,0,0,0], 
  [0,0,0,0,0,0], 
  [0,0,0,0,0,0], 
  [0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Since `am[i][j]` can only be `0` or `1` the only time `am[i][j] > am[i][k] + am[k][j]` is true is when `am[i][k] + am[k][j] === 0` and  when that's true you set `am[i][j]` to equal 0. I think you misunderstand the algorithm. Floyd–Warshall is for a weighted graph that you initialize to weights of infinity. But you don't have any weights in your graph.

Comment: Oh that's totally right. Thank you!